# An alternative to Fortran CPP-like preprocessors

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, fortran90, preprocessor

I'm looking for an alternative to `#ifdef #else #enddef` in my Fortran 90 code.
Is there another way to control what `use` statements are executed when a module is called? I want to get away from `#include` files in my complex system.

For example, this is what I have now.

```
#include "defs.h"
module X
#ifdef Sys
use ....
#else
use ....
#endif
implicit none

snip...
#ifdef Sys
some block of code...
#else
some block of code...
#endif
end module X
```

In defs.h Sys is defined. I would like find an alternative to using defs.h to control the `#ifdef....` parts of the code.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Isn't the use of `#include` entirely separate from the use of `#ifdef` etc? Do you want to avoid both constructs or just the `#include`?

Comment: I'm compiling a fortran system using FCM, a system that is very new and unknown to me. It cannot find a include file that I added even though the paths are correct. I want to control the execution of certain ´use´ command and block codes that were controlled using `#ifdef XXX` where `XXX` is defined in an `#include` file. So yes I want to avoid both constructs if it is possible. It is easy to do this for block part of the code but the preamble, i.e., `use ....` is more difficult and the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: It would be really helpful to show the code example and illustrate what exactly you are doing. Otherwise people start suggesting things and you will say it is not applicable because of some reason you did not mention.

Comment: Ok. I've added an example. I hope this makes this less ambiguous.

Comment: An alternative way of defining pre-processor variables is to add them in the arguments passed to the pre-processor, e.g. `cpp -DSys` should ensure `Sys` is defined.

Comment: I should note your real issue appears to be that when using FCM it `cannot find a include file that I added even though the paths are correct.`, it might be better to focus on fixing this rather than coming up with a workaround?

Comment: @ d_1999 You have a point, but FCM is a queer system with horrible docs and few users. Finding a workaround seems the fastest way to solve this issue. I don't quite follow you suggestion. I'm using modules so I need a way to control the `use ...` part of the code.

Comment: There are (at least) two ways that the `Sys` symbol can become defined, the first is to have an explicit `#define Sys` somewhere in the source code (including in included files), the other is to tell the pre-processor that the symbol is defined using the `-DSys` argument to the pre-processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start off by repeating what was noted in the comments: The correct solution to your real problem is really to work out why when using FCM the compiler can't find the file you wish to include.

To fix your specific problem, due to not being able to successfully `include` a given file that provides various definitions we can instead define symbols through arguments passed to the compiler.

Consider the following, stored in `test.fpp`

```
#ifdef Sys
#warning "This messages tells you Sys is defined"
#else
#warning "This messages tells you Sys is NOT defined"
#endif

program test
  implicit none
  write(*,'("For clarity we will now print defined if Sys is defined or not defined if Sys is not defined")')
#ifdef Sys
  write(*,'("Defined")')
#else
  write(*,'("Not defined")')
#endif
end program test
```

We can compile this using `gfortran -ffree-form test.fpp -o test`. This will produce:

```
test.fpp:4:2: warning: #warning "This messages tells you Sys is NOT defined" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "This messages tells you Sys is NOT defined"
  ^
```

and doing `./test` gives the output

```
For clarity we will now print defined if Sys is defined or not defined if Sys is not defined
Not defined
```

If we now compile using `gfortran -ffree-form test.fpp -o test -DSys` we instead see the message

```
test.fpp:2:2: warning: #warning "This messages tells you Sys is defined" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "This messages tells you Sys is defined"
  ^
```

and running `./test` gives us

```
For clarity we will now print defined if Sys is defined or not defined if Sys is not defined
Defined
```

Comment: Typical XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @ d_1999 Brilliant. I didn't know that I could circumvent the defs.h file and pass the definition via the -D flag. This is what I was looking for. I have sent out a query to the FCM folks but that can take weeks. It's been my experience that many people do not know what FCM is, and alternative to make, although similar. But I'm stuck with this system so therefore I sought a quick workaround. Given the situation, I do not think this is a true XY problem - although I'm grateful for the enlightenment :-) This is why I tried to formulate the question not as a problem but rather another method.